# Работа с указателем пагинации Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel

Я пишу модуль сообщений. Необходимо сделать пагинацию для них при скролле. при написании новых сообщений они подгружаются на страницу vue.js в конец. если запустить стандартную пагинацию после написания сообщения(ий) происходит некорректная подгрузка с повторением сообщений, тк массив увеличился а указатель пагинации все там-же. как это можно обойти?

Answer (score 1):

Ты ж все равно (по факту) ведешь нумерацию.
Передавай параметр *page* при дозагрузке страницы и храни в переменной компонента *data* текущий номер подгруженной страницы.

```
onScroll(){
  let self = this
  this.$http.get('/comments?page'+self.nextPage).then((response) => {
    self.nextPage++;
  }, (response) => {
    // error callback
  });
}
```